# A simple class of Python can kill Spyder4.1.4 (Python3.8)

Tags: python

On the way learning Python, I have read some class examples and tried to practice. But how can this piece of code can kill Spyder4.1.4 (Python3.8) by just running?

```
p=Point(101,202,0)
```

Kernel died, restarting...

```
    class Point():
        id=0
        def __init__(self, x, y, z:float=0):
            self._x = x; self._y = y; self._z = z; self.id+=1
        @property
        def x(self):
            return self._x
        @x.setter# to define a "non-public member"
        def x(self, value):
           self._x=value
        @property
        def y(self):
            return self._y
        @y.setter
        def y(self, value):
           self._y=value
        @property
        def xy(self):
            return [self._x,self._y]
        @xy.setter
        def xy(self,xval,yval):
           self._x=xval;self._y=yval
        @property
        def z(self):
            return self._z
        @z.setter
        def z(self, value):
            self._z=value
        @property
        def id(self):
            return self.id
```

I have tried Jupyter notebook or https://ideone.com/hjUDTU. But none is working. I am really lost...

Comment: Always post your error message or traceback

Comment: You are recursing beyond the stack limit. Why do you think you need a property for a simple attribute?

Comment: @brunson, there is no traceback or error message at all. But it is mostly possible that my stack was run out.